# passing data of one then to another in promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

```
Promise.all(events)
    .then(data => {
        return events.map(obj => 
            !isEmpty(obj.space) && {space_name: obj.space.name, ...obj}
        )
    })
    .then(data => //how to get resolved data of above's then

    )
```

I can't pass my data from the first then to the second, any step I missed out?

Comment: At the minute you seem to be doing nothing with the result of the `Promise.all(events)` - `data` in the first `.then` is the resolved value from that. But you do nothing with that argument. `data` in the second `then` would be the result of the `events.map...` (which I assume, as `events` should be set of Promises, will not/should not work properly)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.map` instead of `events.map`?

Comment: `how to get resolved data of above's then` - that would be the `data` argument - your problem is that `events.map` looks fishy, because, events would be an array of promises, and promises don't usually have a property called `space`

Comment: I think you need to post events data here. Because if you really used "events.map", "events" looks like an object, not promise array. But if it's wrong (theoretically, you need to write "data.map", not "events.map"), we need to see events data to understand what's wrong. Maybe you don't resolve promises.

Answer (score 0):

```
let p1, p2, promiseArr
p1 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(2)
})
p2 = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    resolve(8)
})
promiseArr = [p1,p2]
Promise.all(promiseArr)
    .then(data => 
        data.map(value => 
            value*value
        )
    )
    .then(data =>
        console.log(data)
    )
```

Prints `[4, 64]` as expected.

Please check your code again or post a full example.